# Issues Deploying Site with Git & PHP (Cpanel/WHM Server)

Tags: php, git, deployment, github, cpanel

We are trying to automatically deploy our web application using Git, GitHub, and PHP on a Cpanel/WHM server.

I've tried, using the information in the article below, to set up a deploy script on our server that GitHub posts to when we push to the repo.

https://gist.github.com/1809044

Unfortunately, it seems that the fact that apache is running scripts as "nobody" is preventing the script from running. We created SSH keys as the account's user, and the git pull command is not running.

Is there any way to successfully pull a git repo from GitHub on a deploy hook and have it update without installing something complex like Jenkins?

Comment: Jenkins is NOT complex to install or use. It can be set up in minutes for a simple case.

Comment: You maybe could use a setuid or setguid script.

Comment: We have Jenkins installed on another network, so we are familiar with using it to deploy. It IS more complicated than a simple PHP script though, and we were just hoping to set something simple up that we can use on smaller websites.

Comment: Can I use setuid or setguid to set the ID to nobody? Our web server is running scripts as nobody, not the account's username. That seems to be our biggest problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have control over how apache runs? I'm dealing with some e-mail/spam issues. I've also been reading that if you run suPHP, your apache will run as the user of that account.  Sounds like that might be what you need.

Comment: This is indeed how to get it to work, unfortunately changing the way PHP runs on your system can have other consequences so be sure to research it for yourself. We had a lot of permissions issues after making the change.